# Нужны ли запятые и правильно ли они поставлены?

Tags: пунктуация

Вариант 1.
Он закончил школу,
и когда он освободился,
он смог закончить университет,
и теперь, работает инженером,
в общественной организации.

Вариант 2.
Он закончил школу,
и когда он освободился,
он смог закончить университет
и теперь работает инженером
в общественной организации.

Comment: Взятое отдельно, "освободился" означает "вышел на свободу", "освободился из тюрьмы". Но в данном тексте, если судить по хронологии, автор имел в виду "демобилизовался", "освободился из армии". Текст нужно исправить.

Comment: И стилистика непонятная, откуда это акценты? Почему "смог окончить университет" а не просто окончил его. Почему именно "когда освободился" неизвестно откуда? Почему важно что именно в общественной организации работает? Это престижно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Он окончил школу и, когда  освободился,  смог окончить университет и теперь работает инженером в общественной организации.**

Можно, конечно, максимально упростить предложение, но для этого надо знать контекст (например, что значит освободился).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но кажется у Вас пропущена запятая перед союзом "и", в части предложения "университет и теперь работает ".

Comment: Вариант 1 (запятая не ставится). Союз И - неповторяющийся при однородных членах: Он окончил школу и смог окончить университет и теперь работает инженером в общественной организации. Первые два сказуемых близки по значению и связаны союзом И, а затем эта пара соединяется с третьим сказуемым. Вариант 2. Запятая ставится. Это сложносочиненное предложение, так как содержит два сообщения, разделенные наречием "теперь".Он окончил школу и, когда освободился, смог окончить университет,  и теперь (он) работает инженером в общественной организации.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые ох как нужны! Поставлены они ох как неправильно!

Игнорируя неуместно повторяющееся местоимение "он" и неверное употребление глагола "закончить" (учебные заведения *о*канчивают), расставляем знаки, убираем лишние:

*Вариант 1. Он закончил школу, и, когда он освободился, он смог закончить* *университет и теперь работает инженером в общественной организации.*

*Вариант 2. Он закончил школу, и, когда он освободился, он смог закончить* *университет и теперь работает инженером в общественной организации.*

Comment: А чем варианты отличаются?

Answer (score 1):

1) Куча ненужных запятых в первом варианте
2) Неправильное употребление местоимений
3) Как понять, от чего он освободился? Если это не вырвано из контекста, то смысл предложения нарушается
4) Можно использовать причастие вместо “когда”
5) В ответе выше верно сказано, учебное заведение оканчивают
6) Вместо “смог окончить” я бы написал “окончил”

> Он окончил школу и, освободившись, окончил университет, а/и теперь работает инженером в общественной организации.

Звучит бредово, исправим:

> Он окончил школу, окончил университет и теперь работает инженером в общественной организации.

Answer (score 1):

Взятое отдельно, "освободился" означает "вышел на свободу", "освободился из тюрьмы". Предположительно, нужно заменить "освободился" на "демобилизовался" (это дает нормальную последовательность событий).

**Он окончил школу, а когда демобилизовался, смог окончить университет, и теперь он работает инженером в общественной организации.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А разве запятая перед союзом "и" нужна "Спасибо за ответ!"?

Comment: В данном случае два предложения, две основы: (1) он окончил + смог окончить, (2) он работает. Это ССП, запятая нужна.

Comment: Повтор местоимения "он".

Comment: @Jasmin Верно !

Comment: @Jasmin. Да, повтор. И что это значит, по-Вашему? Что-то не так?

Comment: Повтор всегда нежелателен и обычно считается стилистической неточностью.

Comment: Всегда ли? "Потирая висок, в котором от адской утренней боли осталось только тупое, немного ноющее воспоминание, прокуратор всё силился понять, в чём причина его душевных мучений. И быстро он понял это, но постарался обмануть себя. Е. Ему ясно было, что сегодня днём **он** что-то безвозвратно упустил, и теперь **он** упущенное хочет исправить какими-то мелкими и ничтожными, а главное, запоздавшими действиями" (Булгаков).

Comment: Я же написала: обычно. Повтор может быть средством художественной выразительности, как у Булгакова, например. А в нашем примере вряд ли можно так считать.

Comment: На мой взгляд, я остался "в рамках приличий"(стараясь сохранить стиль оригинала) Вот еще: Человек разводит вокруг себя руками и потерянно озирается, будто медленно кружит на одном месте, будто он плыл, и довольно умело плыл, но его ослепило закатным солнцем, полоснуло по глазам лучом, **он** сбился, и теперь **он** вслепую плывет, озирается, не может найти берега. [Нина Садур. Сад (1994)]

Comment: "Теперь он" как итог.

Comment: По-моему,  последнее местоимение лишнее, никакой выразительности в нем нет. Надо только перестановку сделать:...он сбился, и теперь   плывет вслепую, озирается, не может найти берега.

Comment: Не знаю, не знаю. Я так думаю: человек ведет себя так, как будто плывет вслепую; все остальное — в середине; чтобы отделить "вслепую плывет" от серединки, нужно снабдить сказуемое "плывет" собственным подлежащим.